# connect mysql to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, drupal

i'm working with a drupal installation, that uses mysql to create a new user, that has to put his email to be created (its type in mysql is varchar(64)), and then goes to the actual webpage, that works with postgresql, and the user has to put his email another time and then save. Actually the new user table is created in postgres as soon as he puts the email (primary key).

what i would like is a function, or something that as soon as the new user is created in mysql, it automatically connects to postgres to save the email there. Is it possible? How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider a "foreign data wrapper" (FDW).

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#mysql_fdw

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html