# Search from postgresql and filtered by mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, search

I have a problem in dealing of two different database. Postgresql and Mysql.

I have a simple search on my website that search rental properties from a certain location and with a certain condition.

On my Postgresql, a table holds coordinates and radius of a rental property and from my Mysql a table holds the properties attributes like beds,rooms,price etc.

I can correctly retrieve the data. However when using pagination. Page 1 will have 5 rows, Page 2 will have 10 rows, Page 3 will have 20 rows and etc. Btw, each page has a maximum of 25 rows.

To know the problem, let's have scenario:

```
lat = 14.00000
long = 121.00000
rad = 50000
```

when I query this to postgresql...

```
SELECT * FROM postgretable WHERE ST_DWithin(lat_long,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(long lat)', 4326), rad)
```

I got 25 rows in total.
Now I want this to be filtered using the other conditions that can be found in the mysql database.

Other conditions:

```
Beds = 2
Bathrooms = 5
price 1000

SELECT * FROM mysqltable WHERE id = $result['id'] AND beds = 2,Bathrooms = 5, price = 1000
```

When executed from mysql using the data from postgresql
I got 6 results.

---

I can't think of anything to solve this one. Using an array or something?
I know this can be properly done if I'm using single database and only use LEFT JOIN or any similar. But I'm dealing with two database.

is there any other way to solve this problem? THanks

Comment: If you have any control over the DB structure. why wouldn't you just have all this data in one database service?

Comment: Why are you using 2 different databases?

Comment: I could argue that there's nothing wrong with using two databases, and I've certainly joined data from two databases on two different servers under MSSQL... but two different database systems? Hrmmm.

Comment: Please show the table definitions involved and most importantly the select statement you are using.

Comment: @RobertH - Searching with geometry is much faster in postgresql compared to mysql
a_horse_with_no_name - i'm using this kind of statement to query all properties from a certain location.

"SELECT * FROM postgretable WHERE ST_DWithin(lat_long,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(long lat)', 4326), radius)"
--this returns all the properties.Now I'm going to filter them using the mysql using foreach of the result
"SELECT * FROM mysqltable WHERE id = $result['id'] AND beds = 2,baths = 2, price = 1000"
--if its accepted then add to final array, this will be display on the page, say the final array has 6 rows.

Comment: Are you doing server-side programming?  If so, what language are you using?  In Python this could be fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the answer to this question:

[connect mysql to postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317229/connect-mysql-to-postgresql)

(if I add any more I'd be plagiarizing)